# htaccess mod rewrite NOT

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small problem with url rewriting on apache.

I would like it that it ignores the admin/ folder from rewriting.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?cat=$1&name=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

I have triend doing it myself but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to put conditions on a `RewriteRule`.  Unless all of the conditions match, the RewriteRule won't be applied.  In your case, I'll assume your admin folder is located at `http://yoursite.com/admin`, so a rule like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/*
```

Put that before the `RewriteRule` that you want to prevent from being applied.  The order of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives is important, so be sure of where you're putting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be more of a ServerFault thing, but there's a really quick answer: if you put

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ - [L]
```

*before* your other rewriting rules, that should prevent any URL transformations from being applied to URLs starting with `admin/`.